# Laravel 5.3 - Carbon Date - UTC offset get timezone name

Tags: php, laravel, datetime, php-carbon

I am trying to get a timezone name from a UTC offset in Laravel 5.3 using Carbon. Code listed below any help would be much appreciated.

```
/* current code iteration */
$utcOffset = -5;
$timezone = Carbon::now($utcOffset)->timezone->getName();
echo $timezone;
// Result: -05:00
// Expected Result: EST

/* tried code */
$timezone = Carbon::now($utcOffset)->tzName;
// Result: -05:00

/* What I used prior to Carbon */
$timezone = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $utcOffset * 3600, TRUE);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$timezone = $dateTime->format('T');'
```

What am I missing? I feel daft..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tried updating Carbon to no evail ended up using the old datetime class.

```
$timezone = timezone_name_from_abbr(null, $utcOffset * 3600, TRUE);
$dateTime = new DateTime();
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone($timezone));
$timezone = $dateTime->format('T');
```

Answer (score 5):

**Preface:**

The accepted answer works in most cases but as mentioned in the user contributed notes area of [timezone_name_from_abbr()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.timezone-name-from-abbr.php), there are issues with using the function, like [returning false instead of actual timezone](http://bugs.php.net/44780) and returning a "historical" (i.e. deprecated) timezone identifier rather than the current standard one for a given location. Which are still valid to this date.

Also, the original code returns the value as expected, as long as you know that as per Carbon docs, if you look at https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-timezone

> the original name of the timezone (can be region name or offset string):

One more thing to note here is that, it is considered not reliable to derive timezone off of offset value as it does not take into consideration the DST observed periods offset.

So, this all to actually say that deriving timezone off of offset is not always possible.

**Answer:**

But since the OP mentioned Carbon and timezone based on offset, as per the Carbon docs as of now, the answer should be

```
$date = Carbon::now('-5');
echo $date->tzName;
```

Answer (score 1):

In a new `Carbon` it is `timezoneName` property;

```
$now = Carbon::now(-5);
echo $now->timezoneName;
//or 
echo $now->timezone->getName();
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
$now = Carbon::now(-5);

echo $now->timezone;
// prints 'America/Chicago'
```

Comment: based on [git repo](https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon/blob/master/src/Carbon/Carbon.php#L240) it is  `$now->tzName`

Comment: That returns the error: Object of class DateTimeZone could not be converted to string.

Comment: What about `->tzName`? I've posted a screenshot from tinker that they both work with my installation.

Comment: ->tzName returns the offset of -05:00

Comment: I can't help you then. According to docs `->tzName` should work, according to my testing it works. There has to be some other difference then. If it helps I tested it on project with Laravel 5.3 and carbon version 1.22.1.

Comment: I'm using carbon version 1.14. Do you know how to update it?

Comment: Hmm it should update itself with `composer update` I think.